# How to create a new column and save to csv after rate limit is encountered?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping

I am trying to get the followers count of a list of users and save it to csv.

Here's how my code looks like.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep

def getFollowerCount(Username):
   url = 'https://somewebsite.com'+ Username
    r = requests.get(url)
    if r.status_code == 429:
            time.sleep(1)
            
    else:
       # do something to return the followers count

df['follower_count'] = df['Username'].apply(getFollowerCount)

df.to_csv('df.csv')
```

But when the rate limit is exceeded, the new column 'follower_count' is not created. But I still want to get the list of follower count that has executed. How do I solve this issue?

Desperately in need of help, appreciate every contribution, thank you.

Comment: your function didn't return anything. you need to return to use apply in your custom function

 `def f(x):
    return pd.Series([x.min(), x.max()], index=['min', 'max'])


sample_1.apply(f, axis=0)`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `try` `except` block inside the function and see if it works:

```
def getFollowerCount(Username):
    url = 'https://somewebsite.com'+ Username
    r = requests.get(url)
    try:
        if r.status_code == 429:
           time.sleep(1)
            
        else:
           # do something to return the followers count
    except:
           print('Rate limit exceeded')
```